# Auto generate meta data value in post

Tags: automatic-updates

I have a website with more than 50,000 posts. For SEO we use 'All in one SEO'.

Unfortunately I have never written the META Title, META Description or META keywords for any of the posts. Now writing these META info for all the posts is a gigantic job.

We have a specific solution in mind to update all the posts.

To explain farther:

If the heading of the post is: Bad Boy

- META title will be: Bad Boy
- META keyword will be: Bad Boy
- The META description will be: 1 2 3 4 5 6 Bad Boy 7 8 9 10.

If the post category is : tree
where '1 2 3 4 5 6' and '7 8 9 10' will be fixed values

If the heading of the post is: Good Boy

- META title will be: Good Boy
- META keyword will be: Good Boy
- The META description will be: x y z m n Good Boy a v b o i.

If the post category is : bee
where 'x y z m n' and 'a v b o i' will be fixed values

Can you give me the program snippet by inserting which, I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Saving this data persistently seems like excessive approach. Since there is no human input (only logic), there is no benefit to storing results - just keep the logic. More so if logic changes next week you won't need to re-save everything.

Basically I would instead during output check is post has value and if not apply the one generated automatically. I don't have that plugin on hand to advise on specific point in code, but I would assume it should allow programmatic access to that in *some* form.

Comment: Hi Rarst, Yes true. I need a programmatic approach. Otherwise, the job is so huge that it can't be done manually.